# pubspec.yaml have version solving issues. HTML, SVG, RANDOM AVTAR plugins have version issue

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, depends, pubspec.yaml

after upgrade flutter 3 I am facing this version solving issue.

1. HTML version not sported SVG
2. if I am choosing SVG different version so RANDOM_AVTAR is not sported.

both plugin sported or dependent on different version an I need all this how can I control this versions.

**ERRORS:**

Because every version of random_avatar depends on flutter_svg ^1.0.3 and demo depends on flutter_svg 0.23.0, random_avatar is forbidden.
So, because demo depends on random_avatar ^0.0.2, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because demo depends on random_avatar ^0.0.2, version solving failed.)

Running "flutter pub get" in fluter...
Because demo depends on flutter_html ^2.1.5 which depends on flutter_svg >=0.22.0 <1.0.0, flutter_svg >=0.22.0 <1.0.0 is required.
So, because demo depends on flutter_svg ^1.0.3, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because demo depends on flutter_svg ^1.0.3, version solving failed.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: which version of  flutter_svg is on ur pubspec.yml

Comment: flutter_svg: ^1.1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for work around you can use

```
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
  flutter_html: 3.0.0-alpha.5
  random_avatar: ^0.0.7
```

Comment: Hello, how you got the correct versions?  please tell me the way.

Comment: This version is not the current stable version it is in testing or in-development, you can check the github  of the package and then click versions.